# Getting emails one by one using Javamail Api

Tags: java, multithreading, api, jakarta-mail

I am using Javamail API to fetch emails from a Gmail IMAP server.

I am using `Message[] messages = inbox.search(term)` to get all the Emails from the server. Instead I wanted to get the mails one by one so that I can save them in the database one by one instead of getting the whole array, so that another service can start parsing the emails instead of waiting for all the emails to come and then parse because it is a time consuming process.

Comment: I suppose you could get a list of messages first (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) limiting the `maxResults` to 1 - get the message Id and then fetch it individually (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) - then you might need to mark it as `read` (or something - i.e. add a label: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify) and repeat the process until you have fetched all messages

Comment: @ochi let me try if that works. is there something that the api offers for this though?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, I added the relevant API links to my comment.  Are you looking for something else or are you talking about a different API?

Comment: @ochi No I was using the JavaMail API, not the Gmail API to fetch emails.

Comment: I see, I am afraid I am not that familiar with the JavaMail API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The search method doesn't fetch the data for all the messages from the server, it only gets the message numbers of the matching messages from the server.  The Message objects that are returned contain no data until you call a method on the Message object to request some of the data; they're just a reference to the message on the server.

If the search call is too slow, it's not because the data for the messages is being returned to the client, it's because the server is slow searching the messages.  You can see exactly what the client requests and what the server returns by turning on [JavaMail debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).

If you want to prefetch more of the Message data, rather than fetching it on demand, you can use the [Folder.fetch](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Folder.html#fetch-javax.mail.Message:A-javax.mail.FetchProfile-) method.

Comment: That was pretty useful :D